# Vba Lookup value on sheet x if value like or similar to?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook with 2 sheets.

Sheet1:

```
Column B               Column C     Column D      Column E

Dairy Crest Ltd        
Milk Farm
Tuna Family
Guiness
```

Sheet 2:

```
Column A                   Column B     Column C           Column d   
Dairy Crest                James        james@email.com    07874565656
Milk Farm Limited          Kelly        kely@email.com     07874565656
Tuna's Families            Dave         dave@email.com     07874565656
Guiness Prep Limited       Tom          tom@email.com      07874565656
```

I want to match the similar named companies. This can't be a case of saying if value = value because the company name is usually spelt different.

Instead i want to use like or wildcard. Would this work?

If i use Value Like Value this doesn't seem to work.

Where found, i want to copy the contact name, email and contact number over to sheet 1 in the relevant columns.

For some reason this is not working. Please can someone show me where i am going wrong?

Relevant code:

```
  'Start second loop sequence
                With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(3)
               LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
               j2 = 2
               For i2 = 1 To LastRow

               ' === For DEBUG ONLY ===
               Debug.Print ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Range("B" & j2).Value

               If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Range("B" & j2).Value = .Range("A" & i2).Value Then      ' check if Week No equals the value in "A1"

                ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Range("C" & j2).Value = .Range("B" & i2).Value
                ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Range("D" & j2).Value = .Range("D" & i2).Value
                ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Range("E" & j2).Value = .Range("C" & i2).Value

                j2 = j2 + 1

                End If
                Next i2
                End With

                'End Second Loop
```

Full COde:

```
Option Explicit

Sub LoadWeekAnnouncementsFromPlanner()

Dim WB As Workbook
Dim WB2 As Workbook
Dim i As Long
Dim i2 As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim j2 As Long
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet

'Open Planner
'On Error Resume Next
Set WB = Workbooks("2017 Planner.xlsx")
On Error GoTo 0
If WB Is Nothing Then 'open workbook if not open
    Set WB = Workbooks.Open("G:\BUYING\Food Specials\2. Planning\1. Planning\1. Planner\8. 2017\2017 Planner.xlsx", xlUpdateLinksNever, True, Password:="samples")
End If

'Open PhoneBook
'On Error Resume Next
'On Error GoTo 0

' ======= Edit #2 , also for DEBUG ======
With WB.Worksheets(1)
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    j = 2

    For i = 1 To LastRow


        ' === For DEBUG ONLY ===
        Debug.Print CInt(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("I8").Value)


        If CInt(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("I8").Value) = .Range("A" & i).Value Then   ' check if Week No equals the value in "A1"

                ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Range("A" & j).Value = .Range("A" & i).Value
                ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Range("B" & j).Value = .Range("N" & i).Value
                ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Range("H" & j).Value = .Range("K" & i).Value
                ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Range("I" & j).Value = .Range("L" & i).Value

                ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Range("J" & j).Value = .Range("M" & i).Value
                ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Range("K" & j).Value = .Range("G" & i).Value

                ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Range("L" & j).Value = .Range("O" & i).Value
                ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Range("M" & j).Value = .Range("P" & i).Value

                ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Range("N" & j).Value = .Range("W" & i).Value
                ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Range("O" & j).Value = .Range("Z" & i).Value




                 'Start second loop sequence
                With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(3)
               LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
               j2 = 2
               For i2 = 1 To LastRow

               ' === For DEBUG ONLY ===
               Debug.Print ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Range("B" & j2).Value

               If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Range("B" & j2).Value = .Range("A" & i2).Value Then      ' check if Week No equals the value in "A1"

                ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Range("C" & j2).Value = .Range("B" & i2).Value
                ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Range("D" & j2).Value = .Range("D" & i2).Value
                ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Range("E" & j2).Value = .Range("C" & i2).Value

                j2 = j2 + 1

                End If
                Next i2
                End With

                'End Second Loop


               j = j + 1

               End If
               Next i
               End With

End Sub
```

Please can someone show me where i am going wrong?

Comment: Just given the example, if you have the first 4 characters as independent in each company name, you would be able to dim asdf as string, then asdf = left(REF,4).text (may want to use .value instead of .text).  With this, you can match the REF cell with asdf&"*", where if true you copy the row.  That's at least a quick thought to the process, considering I'm only seeing the example chart.

Comment: @Cyril im brand new to vba, how would this be done? do you have an example code?

Comment: Why dont you use LIKE operator? in VBA its as - "IF myValue LIKE '*checkagainstValue*' then do some stuff"

Comment: @DougCoats i tried this and it doesn't return anything

Comment: @user7415328 I didnt notice SO took the asterisks out of my reply. like operator works with single quotes and asterisks ' * * '

Answer (score 0):

This is a good example how to use Like in VBA. Try it in the console window, to get the answers.

```
?"Vito6" Like "V?to6"
True
?"Vito6" Like "Vito#"
True
?"Vito6" Like "V*6"
True
?"Vito6" Like "Vit[a-z]6"
True
?"Vito6" Like "Vit[A-Z]6"
False
?"Vito6" Like "Vit[!A-Z]6"
True
?"12 34" Like "## ##"
True
?"12 34" Like "1[0-9] [0-9]4"
True
```

Answer (score 0):

Will try to elaborate on my thought from the comment I left you:

```
Dim asdf as String
Dim i as Variant
Dim LR as Long

LR = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 to LR 'Sheet1 looks to start on row 3, while Sheet2 looks to start on row2
    asdf = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i+1,2).Value

    If Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(i,1).Value Like "*asdf*" Then 'you left out the asterisks
        'true: copy data
        Else:
        'false: can just be nothing here
        End If

    Next i
```

Something similar to that is what I was suggesting.  Utilized like operator, as suggested by @DougCoats.

Comment: PS, you use LastRow, I input LR because it's what I'm used to... please be aware.

Answer (score 0):

If there's not a specific reason you need VBA, you could apply the solution that @Cyril gave in his comment to an Excel cell formula on Sheet1.

For example, in Sheet1, Cell F1, you can input:

```
=LEFT(B1, 4)
'This would return "Dair"
```

Then, in column A, you could use a nested IF statement:

```
=IF(F1 = "dair", "Dairy Crest", IF(F1 = "milk", "Milk Farm Limited, IF(F1 = "tuna", "Tuna's Families", IF(F1 = "Guiness", "Guiness Prep Limited", "No match))))
```

Comment: sorry should have said the values aren't static they are dynamic as in could be anything when the data is changed

Answer (score 0):

While you can use wildcards to compare strings using the `like` operator , the explicit parts need to be exact. So

1. `"*Dairy Crest*" like "Dairy Crest Ltd"` will work nicely
2. but `"*Tuna Family*" like "Tuna's Families"` will not work.

You can try ***fuzzy lookup*** for matching for the 2nd scenario. It employs probability into the lookup.

Here is the link to the source code.

https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/195635-fuzzy-matching-new-version-plus-explanation.html

Just one note for fuzzy matching with probability, the matching may not be 100% correct if you set the accuracy % too low. If accuracy is important, then set the accuracy % higher.